# Devise not route properly rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I have an app in rails and using devise for `authentication`, the following errors are shown instead route to `sign_in` page

my route.rb content are:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users 
  resources :posts
  get "home/index"
   root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

[image]

I not sure where i was wrong, it would be great if anyone can shows me where the errors is.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your use case for needing a `SessionsController`? If it is only for signing out, you could simply create your own method that calls `sign_out @user`.

Have a look at [this wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview#using-omniauth-without-other-authentications) article and see if it answers your question.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Use `:as` option to configure the resource name.

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```